# 2G / 3G / 4G Network forcing

Tags: android, telecommunication, phone-state-listener, lte, cellinfo

I'm busy writing some code to get signal strength and stuff but would like to programatically "force" my network connection to 2G / 3G / 4G so that for more conclusive measurements. I know there's a lot of applications capable of:

1. forcing connection to a 2g/3g/4g Network
2. forcing to a specific frequency band of channels
3. even forcing measurements to specific cells (CIDs) of cell towers
   but have not had much progress with google thus far.

If someone can please point me into the right direction?, that would be great!

Comment: hi @Paul, ¿did you find a solution that not involve build a custom sdk?

Comment: Hi @jotade, unfortunately didn't find a solution to this specified problem, no. And had to continue with alternative work before I could justify spending additional time on this topic.

Answer (score 2):

I believe your requirements need a rooted phone. However if you want to force the network to be on LTE/GSM?CDMA, you can  trigger those settings through an intent as follows:

```
    try{
        Intent intent = new Intent("android.intent.action.MAIN");
        intent.setClassName("com.android.settings", "com.android.settings.RadioInfo");
        startActivity(intent);
    } catch(Exception e){
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), " Device not supported" , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

`PermissionUtils.java` class for asking permission SDK >= 23

```
public class PermissionUtils {
Context context;
Activity current_activity;

PermissionResultCallback permissionResultCallback;
ArrayList<String> permission_list=new ArrayList<>();
ArrayList<String> listPermissionsNeeded=new ArrayList<>();

String dialog_content="";
int req_code;

public PermissionUtils(Context context)
{
    this.context=context;
    this.current_activity= (Activity) context;
    permissionResultCallback= (PermissionResultCallback) context;
}

public PermissionUtils(Context context, PermissionResultCallback callback)
{
    this.context=context;
    this.current_activity= (Activity) context;
    permissionResultCallback= callback;
}


public void check_permission(ArrayList<String> permissions, String dialog_content, int request_code)
{
    this.permission_list=permissions;
    this.dialog_content=dialog_content;
    this.req_code=request_code;

    if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23)
    {
        if (checkAndRequestPermissions(permissions, request_code))
        {
            permissionResultCallback.PermissionGranted(request_code);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        permissionResultCallback.PermissionGranted(request_code);
    }

}


/**
 * Check and request the Permissions
 *
 * @param permissions
 * @param request_code
 * @return
 */

private  boolean checkAndRequestPermissions(ArrayList<String> permissions,int request_code) {

    if(permissions.size()>0)
    {
        listPermissionsNeeded = new ArrayList<>();

        for(int i=0;i<permissions.size();i++)
        {
            int hasPermission = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(current_activity,permissions.get(i));

            if (hasPermission != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                listPermissionsNeeded.add(permissions.get(i));
            }

        }

        if (!listPermissionsNeeded.isEmpty())
        {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(current_activity, listPermissionsNeeded.toArray(new String[listPermissionsNeeded.size()]),request_code);
            return false;
        }
    }

    return true;
}

/**
 *
 *
 * @param requestCode
 * @param permissions
 * @param grantResults
 */
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String permissions[], int[] grantResults)
{
    switch (requestCode)
    {
        case 1:
            if(grantResults.length>0)
            {
                Map<String, Integer> perms = new HashMap<>();

                for (int i = 0; i < permissions.length; i++)
                {
                    perms.put(permissions[i], grantResults[i]);
                }

                final ArrayList<String> pending_permissions=new ArrayList<>();

                for (int i = 0; i < listPermissionsNeeded.size(); i++)
                {
                    if (perms.get(listPermissionsNeeded.get(i)) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
                    {
                        if(ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(current_activity,listPermissionsNeeded.get(i)))
                            pending_permissions.add(listPermissionsNeeded.get(i));
                        else
                        {
                            Log.i("Go to settings","and enable permissions");
                            permissionResultCallback.NeverAskAgain(req_code);
                           return;
                        }
                    }

                }

                if(pending_permissions.size()>0)
                {
                    showMessageOKCancel(dialog_content,
                            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                                    switch (which) {
                                        case DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE:
                                            Log.d("LOG","ON OK BTN CLICK CALLING CHECK PERMISSION METHOD");
                                            check_permission(permission_list,dialog_content,req_code);
                                            break;
                                        case DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEGATIVE:
                                            Log.i("permisson","not fully given");
                                            if(permission_list.size()==pending_permissions.size()){
                                                Log.d("LOG","ON NO BTN CLICK CALLING Permission Denided METHOD");
                                                //permissionResultCallback.PermissionDenied(req_code);
                                                check_permission(permission_list,dialog_content,req_code);
                                            }
                                            else{
                                                Log.d("LOG","ON NO BTN CLICK CALLING PartialPermissionGranted METHOD");
                                                permissionResultCallback.PartialPermissionGranted(req_code,pending_permissions);
                                            }

                                            break;
                                    }


                                }
                            });

                }
                else
                {
                    permissionResultCallback.PermissionGranted(req_code);
                }
            }
            break;
    }
}


/**
 * Explain why the app needs permissions
 *
 * @param message
 * @param okListener
 */
public void showMessageOKCancel(String message, DialogInterface.OnClickListener okListener) {
    new AlertDialog.Builder(current_activity)
            .setMessage(message)
            .setPositiveButton("Ok", okListener)
            .setNegativeButton("Cancel", okListener)
            .setCancelable(false)
            .create()
            .show();
}

public interface PermissionResultCallback
{
    void PermissionGranted(int request_code);
    void PartialPermissionGranted(int request_code, ArrayList<String> granted_permissions);
    void PermissionDenied(int request_code);
    void NeverAskAgain(int request_code);
}
}
```

Add this permission in your `AndroidManifest.xml`

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
```

TelephonyManagerHelper.java for Information

```
public class TelephonyManagerHelper implements PermissionUtils.PermissionResultCallback {

private Context context;
private Activity current_activity;
private boolean isPermissionGranted;
TelephonyManager telephonyManager;
String Information;


private ArrayList<String> permissions=new ArrayList<>();
private PermissionUtils permissionUtils;
private final static int REQUEST_CHECK_SETTINGS = 2000;


public TelephonyManagerHelper(Context context) {
    this.context=context;
    this.current_activity= (Activity) context;
    permissionUtils=new PermissionUtils(context,this);
    permissions.add(Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE);
    permissions.add(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION);
}

/**
 * Method to check the availability of location permissions
 * */

public void checkpermission()
{
    permissionUtils.check_permission(permissions,"Need permission for getting Phone information",1);
}

private boolean isPermissionGranted() {
    return isPermissionGranted;
}

/**
 * Handles the permission results
 */
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults)
{
    permissionUtils.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode,permissions,grantResults);
}


/**
 * Handles the activity results
 */
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    switch (requestCode) {
        case REQUEST_CHECK_SETTINGS:
            switch (resultCode) {
                case Activity.RESULT_OK:
                    // All required changes were successfully made
                    Information=getInformation();
                    break;
                case Activity.RESULT_CANCELED:
                    // The user was asked to change settings, but chose not to
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
            break;
    }
}

public String getInformation() {
    try{
        telephonyManager= (TelephonyManager) context.getSystemService(context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);

        int phoneType=telephonyManager.getPhoneType();
        String PhoneType="";
        if (phoneType==telephonyManager.PHONE_TYPE_NONE){  //0
            PhoneType="NONE";
        }else if(phoneType==telephonyManager.PHONE_TYPE_GSM){  //1
            PhoneType="GSM";
        }else if(phoneType==telephonyManager.PHONE_TYPE_CDMA){ //2
            PhoneType="CDMA";
        }else if(phoneType==telephonyManager.PHONE_TYPE_SIP){ //3
            PhoneType="SIP";
        }else{
            PhoneType="Not Found";
        }

        int networkType=telephonyManager.getNetworkType();
        String NetworkType="";

        if (networkType==telephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_UNKNOWN){   //0
            NetworkType="UNKNOWN";
        }else if(networkType==telephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_GPRS){ //1
            NetworkType="GPRS";
        }
        else if(networkType==telephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_EDGE){ //2
            NetworkType="EDGE";
        }
        else if(networkType==telephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_UMTS){ //3
            NetworkType="UMTS";
        }
        else if(networkType==telephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_CDMA){ //4
            NetworkType="CDMA";
        }
        else if(networkType==telephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_EVDO_0){ //5
            NetworkType="EVDO 0";
        }
        else if(networkType==telephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_EVDO_A){ //6
            NetworkType="EVDO A";
        }
        else if(networkType==telephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_1xRTT){ //7
            NetworkType="1xRTT";
        }
        else if(networkType==telephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_HSDPA){ //8
            NetworkType="HSDPA";
        }
        else if(networkType==telephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_HSUPA){ //9
            NetworkType="HSUPA";
        }else if(networkType==telephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_HSPA){ //10
            NetworkType="HSPA";
        }else if (networkType==telephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_IDEN){ //11
            NetworkType="IDEN";
        }else if(networkType==telephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_EVDO_B){ //12
            NetworkType="EVDO B";
        }else if(networkType==telephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_LTE){ //13
            NetworkType="LTE";
        }else if(networkType==telephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_EHRPD){ //14
            NetworkType="EHRPD";
        }else if(networkType==telephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_HSPAP){ //15
            NetworkType="HSPAP";
        }else if(networkType==telephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_GSM){ //16
            NetworkType="GSM";
        }else if(networkType==telephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_TD_SCDMA){ //17
            NetworkType="SCDMA";
        }else {                                                       // 18
            NetworkType="IWLAN";
        }


        @SuppressLint("MissingPermission")
        String DeviceId = telephonyManager.getDeviceId();
        @SuppressLint("MissingPermission")
        String PhoneNumber = telephonyManager.getLine1Number();

        @SuppressLint("MissingPermission")
        String SubscribeIdIMSI=telephonyManager.getSubscriberId();

        @SuppressLint("MissingPermission")
        String NetworkCountryISO= telephonyManager.getNetworkCountryIso();
        String NetworkOperator=telephonyManager.getNetworkOperator();
        int MCC = Integer.parseInt(NetworkOperator.substring(0, 3)); // mobile country code
        int MNC = Integer.parseInt(NetworkOperator.substring(3));    // mobile network code

        String NetworkOperatorName=telephonyManager.getNetworkOperatorName();
        String SimCountryIso=telephonyManager.getSimCountryIso();
        String SimOperator=telephonyManager.getSimOperator();
        String SimOperatorName=telephonyManager.getSimOperatorName();
        @SuppressLint("MissingPermission")
        String SimSerialNumber=telephonyManager.getSimSerialNumber();
        int simState=telephonyManager.getSimState();

        String SimState="";
        if (simState==telephonyManager.SIM_STATE_UNKNOWN){ //0
            SimState="UNKNOWN";
        }else if (simState==telephonyManager.SIM_STATE_ABSENT){ //1
            SimState="ABSENT";
        }else if (simState==telephonyManager.SIM_STATE_PIN_REQUIRED){ //2
            SimState="PIN REQUIRED";
        }else if (simState==telephonyManager.SIM_STATE_PUK_REQUIRED){ //3
            SimState="PUK REQUIRED";
        } else if (simState==telephonyManager.SIM_STATE_NETWORK_LOCKED){ //4
            SimState="NETWORK LOCKED";
        }else if (simState==telephonyManager.SIM_STATE_READY){ //5
            SimState="READY";
        }else if (simState==telephonyManager.SIM_STATE_NOT_READY)//6
        {
            SimState="NOT READY";
        }else if(simState==telephonyManager.SIM_STATE_PERM_DISABLED){ //7
            SimState="PERM DISABLED";
        }else if(simState==telephonyManager.SIM_STATE_CARD_IO_ERROR){ //8
            SimState="CARD IO ERROR";
        }else { //9
            SimState="CARD RESTRICTED";
        }


        @SuppressLint("MissingPermission")
        GsmCellLocation gsmCellLocation = (GsmCellLocation) telephonyManager.getCellLocation();
        int CID = gsmCellLocation.getCid(); // CellID
        int LAC = gsmCellLocation.getLac(); // Location Area Code

        Information="Phone Type : "+PhoneType+"\n\n"+
                "Network Type: "+NetworkType+"\n\n"+
                "DeviceId:  "+DeviceId+"\n\n"+
                "PhoneNumber: "+PhoneNumber+"\n\n"+
                "SubscribeIdIMSI :  "+SubscribeIdIMSI+"\n\n"+
                "NetworkCountryISO :  "+NetworkCountryISO+"\n\n"+
                "NetworkOperator :  "+NetworkOperator+"\n\n"+
                "MCC Mobile Country Code:"+MCC+"\n\n"+
                "MNC Mobile Network Code:"+MNC+"\n\n"+
                "NetworkOperatorName :"+NetworkOperatorName+"\n\n"+
                "SimCountryIso :"+SimCountryIso+"\n\n"+
                "SimOperator :"+SimOperator+"\n\n"+
                "SimOperatorName  :"+SimOperatorName+"\n\n"+
                "SimSerialNumber  :"+SimSerialNumber+"\n\n"+
                "Sim State :"+SimState+"\n\n"+
                "cellID :"+CID+"\n\n"+
                "LAC Location Area Code:"+LAC+"\n\n";
    }catch (Exception e){e.printStackTrace();}
    return Information;

}

@Override
public void PermissionGranted(int request_code) {
    Log.i("PERMISSION","GRANTED");
    isPermissionGranted=true;
}

@Override
public void PartialPermissionGranted(int request_code, ArrayList<String> granted_permissions) {
    Log.i("PERMISSION PARTIALLY","GRANTED");
}

@Override
public void PermissionDenied(int request_code) {
    Log.i("PERMISSION","DENIED");
}

@Override
public void NeverAskAgain(int request_code) {
    Log.i("PERMISSION","NEVER ASK AGAIN");
    permissionUtils.showMessageOKCancel("App Required To Get Phone State \nPlease Grant Permission from AppInfo > Permissions > Phone , Location",
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                    switch (which) {
                        case DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE:
                            Intent intent = new Intent();
                            intent.setAction(Settings.ACTION_APPLICATION_DETAILS_SETTINGS);
                            Uri uri = Uri.fromParts("package", BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID, null);
                            intent.setData(uri);
                            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                            context.startActivity(intent);
                            break;
                        case DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEGATIVE:

                            break;
                    }


                }
            });
}

}
```

`SimCardInformationActivity.java` display information

```
public class SimCardInformationActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
 TextView txtSimInformation;
 TelephonyManagerHelper telephonyHelper;
   String Info;
    @Override
     protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_sim_card_information);
    txtSimInformation=findViewById(R.id.txtSimInformation);
    telephonyHelper=new TelephonyManagerHelper(SimCardInformationActivity.this);
    telephonyHelper.checkpermission();

    getTelephonyInformaiton();


}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    Log.d("LOG:On Activity Result","Request Code "+requestCode+"  Result Code"+requestCode);
    telephonyHelper.onActivityResult(requestCode,resultCode,data);
}

// Permission check functions
@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
    // redirects to utils
    Log.d("LOG:onRequestPermResult","Request Code "+requestCode+"  Grant Result"+grantResults);
    telephonyHelper.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode,permissions,grantResults);
}


private void getTelephonyInformaiton() {
      Info=telephonyHelper.getInformation();
      txtSimInformation.setText(Info);
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    getTelephonyInformaiton();
}

}
```

`activity_sim_card_information.xml` for layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.example.app.SimCardInformationActivity">

    <ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtSimInformation"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </ScrollView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Hi Saurabh, thank you so much for this extensive code, the helper class especially helped showing some additional info SIM, Network & Operator related data that can be read and displayed (by scanning through the code). But I am however now interested in forcing specific network connections, for instance forcing to connect to a LTE or GSM network (maybe to do with [ConnectivityManager](http://android.xsoftlab.net/reference/android/net/ConnectivityManager.html)?). Likewise force to connect to 1800MHz band instead of 900Mhz band (as a form of cell selection for measurements) etc ...

Comment: Add `throws SecurityException` right before defining the `public String getInformation()` function to get rid of the annoying error. :)

Comment: Please read [answer] and [edit] your answer to contain an explanation as to why this code would actually solve the problem at hand. Always remember that you're not only solving the problem, but are also educating the OP and any future readers of this post.